# Sort String in C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting

I have a list with a lot of numbers in it. But they are saved as strings because of some additional letters.

I have a list that contains a string column called `jointNumber` my data is like this :

```
1b
a1
10
15
2a
20
21
250
3
34
368
```

Code:

```
List<ViewTestPackageHistorySheet> lstTestPackageHistorySheets =
         _reportTestPackageHistorySheetRepository.ShowReport(Id)
         .OrderBy(i => new { i.LineNumber, i.JointNumber}).ToList();
```

But it doesn't work. Why? As you can see I sort it based on two columns the first column works I mean `linenumber` but it doesn't sort the data based on `jointnumber`.

Comment: `new { i.LineNumber,i.JointNumber}` <- that is not sortable in itself. What you want is `OrderBy(i=> i.LineNumber).ThenBy(i => i.JointNumber)`

Comment: What you are looking for is called "natural sorting", there are existing implementations of this for C# if you google for them.

Comment: What do you mean, "saved as strings because of some additional letters"?  Can you add some examples of what that looks like in your data?

Comment: What order do you expect to get them in?

Comment: I have some letter in my data

Comment: What order do you want the result to be in?  Numeric ignoring letters?  Alphabetical? ASCII-code sorted?

Comment: Your best bet is to write a View in your database provider that removes all non numeric characters and query against that OR execute the sorting in c# and not in the database by materializing the list and THEN ordering it. There are also many questions as to how you expect to order something with characters in it, do you want to strip them, place them on top, bottom, ignore them, etc. This question has way to many issues with little information provided. I am voting to close it based on that.

Comment: Surely when LineNumber is unique, further sorting on a second column would have no effect? Please show example data from both columns you're talking about.

Comment: Where whould `1a` and `b2` go in a numerical sort?  Do you want `1a, b1, 2, 10, etc` (ignore letters entirely), or `1a, 2, 10, ..., b1, etc`, or something different entirely?\

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code at all, I can see that your list is already in alphabetical order.  Did you convert your strings to numeric data types anywhere?